# Tracking Stripe Conversions with Analytics in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, stripe-payments

I have two buttons on my website using Stripe that I would like to track ecommerce conversion and button clicks but I am not sure how to integrate the code in analytics with my HTML page because the purchase does not have a confirmation page and I am not sure what the button action tag is:

```
<form action="/charge.php" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='productName' value='1_device'>
    <script
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="XXXYYYZZZ"
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
          data-name="Single"
          data-description="$1.99 monthly"
          data-panel-label="Subscribe"
          data-label="Single"
          data-amount="199"
          data-allow-remember-me="false">
    </script>
</form>

<form action="/charge.php" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='productName' value='5_device'>
    <script
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="XXXYYYZZZ"
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
          data-name="Family"
          data-description="$9.99"
          data-panel-label="Subscribe"
          data-label="Family"
          data-amount="999"
          data-allow-remember-me="false">
    </script>
</form>
```

Would anyone know what tracking code to place inside the above code to track conversions and clicks? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I know using javascript to declare transaction on click is the common way to do, but I believe declaring a transaction to Google Analytics before it's been completed is a risk of polluting your data with non'existent transactions (if transaction has been droped or rejected).

So in my opinion, the correct way to achieve what you want to do is the following. It requires being comfortable using javascript / jQuery and php.

*Maybe it's a bit too technical for OP, but it might be useful to other readers.*

**According to the question, you want to track two things :**

1. stripe button clicks
2. confirmed e-commerce transactions

The best way to do that in my opinion is to :

1. send an "event" type hit to Google Analytics using javascript, when stripe button is clicked
2. setup a Stripe hook url to catch transaction result (once the transaction has been processed), and in case of success, send a hit to Google Analytics using PHP

This is the first elaborate answer i'll post on SO, i'll try to make it good and useful.

## 1. How to track clicks on a button using javascript & Google Analytics

What you want to use is called "event tracking". Event as in "some event occured, I want to notify GA about it".

The logic here is :

> on stripe button click, send event "stripe button has been clicked" to GA

Assuming your stripe button HTML is something like

```
<button type="submit" class="stripe-button-el" style="visibility: visible;"><span style="display: block; min-height: 30px;">SOME TEXT</span></button>
```

I suggest you use some jQuery to detect clicks on this button.
Here's how I do that : in a .js file :

```
(function($)
{    
    // WHEN DOM IS READY
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    // STRIPE BUTTON CLICK TRACKING 
    $("#stripe-button-form button").each(function()
    {
        var sent = false;
        $(this).click(function(event)
        {
            console.log("click"); // Just to make sure the click has been detected, you can comment this line
            if(!sent)
            {
                ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'intent'); // send hit to GA
                sent = true; // used to make sure the hit is sent only once to GA
            }
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

The

> ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');
>   line is the one you want to customize according to your needs.

- 'send' and 'event' stay the same, don't touch it.
- 'category', 'action', 'label' you can customize. Have a look at Google Analytics documentation or event tracking tutorials for details about the smart way to do that.

Doing so, you'll be able to track each click on your stripe buttons (except repeat clicks, in case someone clicks twice or many times).

## 2. How to track success transactions using Stripe hook and Google Analytics API (Google Measurement Protocol)

Here the logic is :

- Tell Stripe what URL of yours it should send the result to after an payment attempt
- That URL is a php file, where you'll receive the data. If the data sent by Stripe says transaction has been successfull, THEN you'll send the transaction details to Google Analytics. If on the other hand the transaction has failed or not been completed : then do nothing, and don't compromise your GA reports.

### Stripe hook

#### Stripe setup

First, in your Stripe Dashboard, go to Account Settings > Webhooks > Add endpoint. The URL you need to put is the URL from the PHP file you'll use to receive Stripe's payments results.

Lets say : http://example.com/stripe-listener.php
Put the endpoint in test mode, then do the same for live mode.

(and of course, make sure stripe-listener.php exists and is properly located on your server).

#### Your stripe listener

This is a bit long to detail here, so allow me to give you the tutorial where I got all the information : 
https://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-6-payment-receipts/

Basically, you will need to have the Stripe API PHP library sitting on your server so that the following can work. I'll let you figure this out, it's not too complicated once you dive in.

Your stripe-listener.php file (you can name it whatever you want, provided you'r consistent with what you used for Stripe webhook endpoint) should resemble something like that :

```
// STRIPE STUFF
global $stripe_options;
require_once(STRIPE_BASE_DIR . '/lib/Stripe.php');
if(isset($stripe_options['test_mode']) && $stripe_options['test_mode'])
{
    $secret_key = $stripe_options['test_secret_key'];
} else {
    $secret_key = $stripe_options['live_secret_key'];
}
Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');

// grab the event information
$event_json = json_decode($body);


// this will be used to retrieve the event from Stripe
$event_id = $event_json->id;


if(isset($event_id))
{
    try
    {
    // LOAD EVENT DATA FROM STRIPE
    $event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
    $invoice = $event->data->object;


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // NOW DEAL WITH POTENTIAL SITUATIONS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // IF PAYMENT SUCCEEDED
    if($event->type == 'charge.succeeded')
    {
        // Do stuff with data stored in $invoice.
        // For example :
        $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);
        $email = $customer->email;
        $amount = $invoice->amount / 100; // amount comes in as amount in cents, so we need to convert to dollars
        $txn_id = $invoice->id; // transaction unique ID
        $livemode = $invoice->livemode;

        // ....
        // THEN
        // ....

        // Ping Google Analytics 
        if($livemode != false)
        {

            // Event
            if(function_exists("GA_send_event"))
            {
                // Transaction details
                $transaction_ID = $txn_id; // My unique transaction id, retrieved from Stripe
                $transaction_ttc = $amount; // My transaction amount (tax included), retrieved from Stripe
                $transaction_tax = round($amount-($amount/1.2),2); // My tax total amount (I do a bit of calculation to get it, based on french tax system), don't pay too much attention to that
                $product_name = $type; // $type was retrieved from a special value I store in Stripe, but you can use anything you'd like


                // Send transaction details to GA, with a custom function 
                GA_send_transaction($transaction_ID, $transaction_ttc, $transaction_tax, $product_name);
            }
        }
    }


    // WHEREAS IF PAYMENT FAILED
    if($event->type == 'charge.failed')
    {
        // Do some other stuff, like maybe send yourself an email ?
    }

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    wp_die("error");
    exit();
}
}
```

Here the juicy part is

> GA_send_transaction($transaction_ID, $transaction_ttc, $transaction_tax, $product_name);

This is a custom function whose role is to send transaction details to Google Analytics.

This function is defined (and linked to Google Analytics API) thanks to the following library :

### The Google Analytics API ( aka "Google Measurement Protocol")

This is used to send data to Google Analytics using PHP.
The interest of doing that (rather than relying on the usual javascript) is that you're working server-side. In other words : you're not dependant on what the user will do (or not do). Like wait until your confirmation page has loaded, or bail before (and not run your javascript).

- When you want to track a user action / a on-page event : go with the standard javascript functions for Google Analytics
- When you need to make sure what you send is 100% reliable, use a server-side approach, like here.

I've wrapped up a quick PHP library, based on Stu Miller's work : 
http://www.stumiller.me/implementing-google-analytics-measurement-protocol-in-php-and-wordpress/

The library I currently use (as a Wordpress plugin) I've just put on GitHub for you to use, adapt and (hopefully) improve (i'm pretty sure there's a lot of room for improvement).

Here : https://github.com/blegrand/google-analytics-php-library

(feel free to improve it, and bear in mind it's my first public repo on GitHub)

Hope that'll help !

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

### Capture click event

```
<script>    
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {    
  if (event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("stripe-button")) {    
    var data = event.target.previousElementSibling.dataset;
  }    
});    
</script>
```

### Data

All data are after click accessible in dataset object:

```
/* All data fields
data["key"]
data["image"]
data["name"]
data["description"].replace(/\D/g, '');
data["panel-label"]
data["label"]
data["amount"]
data["allow-remember-me"]
*/
```

## Tie data with Google Analytics transaction

All together should looks like this:

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.contains("stripe-button")) {
    var data = event.target.previousElementSibling.dataset;   

    var transactionID = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);

    var transactionValue = data["description"].replace(/\D/g, '');
    // set up ga
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': transactionID, // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': data["name"], // Product name. Required.                          
      'category': data["label"], // Category or variation.
      'price': transactionValue,// Unit price.
      'quantity': 1 // Quantity.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': transactionID,  // Transaction ID. Required.     
      'revenue': transactionValue // Grand Total.         
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');
  }
});
</script>
```

## Documentation

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Does this go along with where the Google Analytics tracking code is (before </head>)? Also, are Transaction ID and Product Name supposed to be setup in GA goal conversions?

Comment: @Goose You can add this script where ever you want. It only works after click on a button. Then set up transaction variables as you need and mean. Setting up new goal is not necessary. They are by default in Ecommerce reports. check documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Ok gotcha - what do you mean by "set up transaction variables as you need and mean"?

Comment: @Goose That mean I don't know, what exactly mean 'key' or 'description' etc. Is key the same like ID? Or SKU? And what about amount? It looks like price but in integer, so if it is not quantity, then set quantity manually to 1.

Comment: Key in stripe is the private API key so I dont think I would put that there

Comment: @Goose ok, if you do not use any transaction ID, then we can use random number. I am updating my answer with this.

Comment: Seems to me sending transaction payload to GA on stripe button submit would be a mistake.

At that point, transaction hasn't been completed yet : it could be aborted or be rejected due to invalid data, but you're litteraly saying GA it's an OK transaction. As a consequence, your analytics would count transactions (and revenue) that didn't go through, your dataset would be polluted and unreliable.

Comment: @Baptiste I am very happy that you disagree with my solution. Try to consider two additional information. 1. Author of the questions says: "the purchase does not have a confirmation page" so it is hard to track conversion on unknown place. 2. If you know your conversions are "just clicks on a stripe" I think it is ok if you use this information in time of analyzing and making conclusions based on data.

Comment: @jakub kriz in a scenario without confirmation page (or when there's a doubt whether confirmation page will be loaded), I personally hit Google Analytics server side, using php and Google Analytics API (Google Measurement Protocol). All you have to do is declare an url where Stripe can send the result to after a payment has been processed. If it's a success, you retrieve info from Stripe API, and hit Google Analytics to declare the transaction. That way you're 100% sure you only send reliable data to GA,since it's been processed and validated already.

Comment: @Baptiste I absolutely agree with using Measurement Protocol on server side to confirm transaction. There is not better way. There still remain question, if in this case is possible to reconfigure Stripe Payment service or their API to send it via MP. And if the Author is able to do it. If you will write tutorial, how to track this particular conversions with Stripe directly, I will vote for you and downvote myself.

Comment: Sure, I can try, although I don't do it for the sake or arguing or being right :) Should I do it here, or in another topic ?

Comment: Ok i've explained my approach, hope it'll help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41985331/614473